# Docker compose with images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I have installed on ubuntu docker, and then downloaded influxdb and grafana dockers from repository, using:
    docker pull influxdb
    docker pull grafana

I want to use docker compose to up the service, but reading the documentation on the official site, the 2 step is to create a python file to define the container. This is what I did do not need, because I have downloaded from the official docker repository.

How can I run using docker-compose granfaa and influxdb?

Edit: I have tried with this docker-compose file:

[image]

But it gives me an error:
Mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml" line 4, colimn 24

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: I dont know how to run grafana and influxdb dockers using docker-compose without generating a python file

Comment: which python file you talking about , please refer to the documentation

Comment: In the official documentation, in getting started the second step isto create a python file..

Comment: please provide your file as a text

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the [basics](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), it's actually quite simple. In a `docker-compose.yml` file you compose your dockers. You posting this question signifies the fact that you did 0 research and posted to SO to find a solution, which is not respected in the community.

Within your docker-compose give the name of your service, then define the servuce below with an image, ports, volumes, etc.

```
influxdb:
  image: influxdb:latest
  container_name: influxdb
  ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    - "8086:8086"
    - "8090:8090"
  env_file:
    - 'env.influxdb'
  volumes:
    # Data persistency
    # sudo mkdir -p /srv/docker/influxdb/data
    - /srv/docker/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb

telegraf:
  image: telegraf:latest
  container_name: telegraf
  links:
    - influxdb
  volumes:
    - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro

grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana:latest
  container_name: grafana
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  env_file:
    - 'env.grafana'
  links:
    - influxdb
  volumes:
    # Data persistency
    # sudo mkdir -p /srv/docker/grafana/data; chown 472:472 /srv/docker/grafana/data
    - /srv/docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
```

To run simply enter the command `docker-compose up` in the dir which has this docker-compose file.

[Reference](https://github.com/nicolargo/docker-influxdb-grafana/blob/master/docker-compose.yml%60)

Comment: I have tried this, using only influxdb, but doesnt works, edited on the OP

Comment: The problem is your indentation. Firstly, If you want to post code to SO dont post an image, post your code like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

If you post your code, I can show you what's wrong. But the problem is your spaces (indents) After influxdb you have given two tab spacings. Jus give one.

Comment: Can you use the entire file I've posted, as is. Just copy-paste it to a new file called `docker-compose.yml` and hit go? If it works, edit this file.